# How can i set qouta on docker volume with zfs

Tags: docker, docker-compose, volumes, zfs

I want to set a hard limit for the volume to grow. How can i do it with docker-compose? Right now i have zfs as the fs for /var/lib/docker. My current volume part looks like this:

```
volumes:
  vol1:
    driver_opts:
      size: "2G"
```

But this does give me an error: quota size requested but no quota support

Comment: This was previously available via the [storage_opt](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#storage_opt) option in `docker-compose.yml`, but that is no longer supported in version 3.

Comment: I am using version 2.4, so it should be available.

Comment: The filesystem should have support for it, otherwise it will not work. ex4 will not work with this option even if using compose version 2.4